# drush appears to not be respecting --no-backup

Tags: drush

My server has a great backup system in place.  I do not need additional backups dropped into my home directory.

Reading the [drush docs](http://drush.ws/) gave me the impression that the `--no-backup` option, would instruct drush to not make a backup.

```
$ drush --version
drush version 4.5
```

When I update a module with the --no-backup option it seems to be ignored.

```
$ ls ~/
creds
$ drush dl drush --no-backup --yes
Would you like to back up your current drush version 4.5 to /home/username/drush-backups/unknown/20110823223228 and replace it with drush 4.5? (y/n): y
drush backed up to /home/username/drush-backups/unknown/20110823223228/drush  [ok]
Project drush (7.x-4.5) downloaded to                                [success]
/srv/www/_drupal_.example.org/drush.
Drush successfully updated to version 7.x-4.5.                       [success]
$ ls ~/
creds  drush-backups
```

Am I missing something obvious here?  I have tried changing the order of the parameters, but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bug report for a contributed module, and needs to be dealt with in the module's issue queue

Answer (score 2):

This is a Drush bug, and would best be raised in the issue queue.  By coincidence, someone recently posted this: http://drupal.org/node/1741108